# How can I pass data from parent component to child component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an Player Form component that is being used for adding and updating. Player Form is inside another component that is the whole page: Update Player. Since I'm new with React, I have still problems understanding the life cycle.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import PlayerForm from './PlayerForm';
//import axios from '../index';

    class UpdatePlayer extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                id: props.match.params.id,
                firstname: '',
                lastname: ''};
        }
    
        componentDidMount = async () => {
            try {
                const id = this.state.id;
                const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/players/${id}`);
                this.setState({'firstname': response.data.firstname, 
                    'lastname': response.data.lastname});
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error)
            }
        }
    
        /*static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
            return {
                firstname: props.firstname,
                lastname: props.lastname}
        }*/
    
        handleSubmit = (firstname, lastname) => {
            const data = {
                firstname,
                lastname
            }
        }
    
        render() {
            console.log('render parent');
            return (
                <PlayerForm data={this.state} buttonLabel="Update" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default UpdatePlayer;
```

The code of the Form component is the following:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    class PlayerForm extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            console.log('create');
            this.state = {
                firstname: props.data.firstname,
                lastname: props.data.lastname}
        }
    
        handleSubmit = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const { firstname, lastname } = this.state;
            this.props.handleSubmit(firstname, lastname);
        }
    
        onChange = (event) => {
            console.log(event.target.name, event.target.value);
            this.setState({ 
                [event.target.name]: event.target.value 
            });
        }
    
        render() {
            console.log('render form!')
            const { firstname, lastname } = this.props.data;
            return (
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} method="post">
                    <div>
                        <label>Firstname</label>
                        <input className="input" placeholder="Firstname" name="firstname" value={firstname} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label>Lastname</label>
                        <input className="input" placeholder="Lastname" name="lastname" value={lastname} onChange={this.onChange}/>
                    </div>
                    <button className="button is-primary" type="submit="> {this.props.buttonLabel}</button>
                </form>
            )
        }
    }
    
    export default PlayerForm;
```

This code is actually working, but I have one major doubt:

1. In the render of the form component, I was using this.state, but I was getting an empty data. I tried many things to update the state in "component Did Update" or "get Derived State From Props", but nothing was working properly. Using props works perfect. Is that the right way? I think it should be neater if using state inside the component.

Comment: Yes Because initial values are empty in the parent component as well. You also render the same time `PlayerForm` component when your parent component renders.  So `PlayerForm` is already called once render. 

You can check loader for getting data from API's response after render form component. Ex: `isLoader === false && <PlayerForm ... />`

Comment: I suggest you to learn about `React Functional Component` rather then learning `React class component`.